# NLP ITSM / Ticket / Datasets for classification and model fine-tuning

Tags: data-request

Currently I am searching for a public ITSM dataset with NLP features (to perform a classification task - or - to use it for BERT model fine-tuning). Are there any public sources available?

Anything dealing with customer support requests, ticket data, IT issues, IT incidents, security incidents or monitoring data would be fine.